# ssh: Could not resolve hostname

Tags: ssh, hadoop

i try to input this command:

`start-dfs.sh`

and the output like this:

`Starting namenodes on [HadoopMaster]
HadoopMaster: ssh: Could not resolve hostname hadoopmaster: Name or service not known`

what did i missed ? i'll appreciate every answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the host can find the node.

```
vim /etc/hosts
```

Then add you ip and the name of the host

```
192.168.0.2     node1
192.168.0.3     node2
```